# GAE flask: ImportError: No module named app

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, flask, importerror

Here is my structure

```
NotificationSys
 app.yaml
 main.py
 email.py
 ...
```

and here is my app.yaml

```
handlers:
 - url: /email/.*  
   script: email.app

 - url: .*  # This regex directs all routes to main.app
   script: main.app
 ...
```

my email.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from flask import Flask, request
from google.appengine.api import mail
import urllib, urllib2, json, datetime, time, converttime, variables, jinja2
from variables import *
app = Flask(__name__)
jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(autoescape=True,
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')))
@app.route('/placement_report')
```

the links under main work fine, but when i make a request to /email/something
this error is given 
ImportError: No module named app

Comment: You need to show, at minimum, the definition of `app` in your email module.  You should provide the [minimum code to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @snakecharmerb 
`app = Flask(__name__)`

Comment: Why is `app = Flask(__name__)` in your email file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the name of handler email.app to emailer.app and the name of the file to emailer.py and everything worked fine. Most probably it was conflicting with some file from some library name email.py.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should only have one `app` object in one file. If you're creating a new Flask app object in each file, that's a mistake. Define it once and import it.
2. The most likely problem is that `email.py` conflicts with the libraries you're using. Change the name of that file.

Comment: Yeah, 2 was the problem.
Can you tell me the reason behind 1? 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_element
The example her contains two app.
`    handlers:
    - url: /profile/.*
      script: user_profile.app
      login: required
    
    - url: /admin/.*
      script: admin.app
      login: admin
    
    - url: /.*
      script: welcome.app`

Comment: I guess to clarify: The App Engine docs you're pointing to aren't Flask-specific, but rather, for WSGI generally, it looks like. You can, technically, have multiple apps running on the same web server, and maybe that's sensible if you want some separation and compartmentalization. But as a rule of thumb, it isn't what Flask programmers do.

Comment: Each Flask app has configuration data, templates, rules for routing requests, all that. If you have two Flask apps, you have all of that twice -- perhaps overlapping. There are perhaps some corner cases where that's desirable, but I don't think it's common.